# HIghcharts.js add catgories with addseries on column chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highcharts column graph which updates dynamically with a new series. I would like to have the x-axis category label also update with the series. I am updating the categories, which I believe is correct, but they are not displaying on the chart. Thoughts?

Thank you.

```
else{
  var chart = $('#chart-area').highcharts();
  categories = chart.xAxis[0].categories;
  categories.push(data.item.test);
  chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories, false);
  chart.addSeries({
      name: data.item.test,
      data: [parseInt(data1)] // in data should be number not string
});
  chart.redraw();
  }
  });
```

Comment: Code looks correct, the problem may be with reusing actual categories, try this: `chart.xAxis[0].categories.slice()` to use copy of categories. If this won't resolve issue, then recreate problem on jsFiddle, I will check this.

Comment: Thanks. Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ayis/sjzoz1or/ Haven't had a second to enter dummy data, but you get the idea.

Comment: I mean some working example, not just a code :)

Comment: Se each category should be another physician? Then problem is how you data is formatted. Try instead of new series, add new point: `chart.series[0].addPoint({ name: 'name', y: parseInt(val) })`. Otherwise you are adding new series, and each of points always is connected to the first category.

Comment: yes. that was the problem. thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use `series.addPoint()` instead of `chart.addSeries()`, for example:

```
chart.series[0].addPoint({ name: 'name', y: parseInt(val) })
```

Otherwise, each series is created for first category always.